# How to run u-boot on QEMU(raspi2)?

Tags: qemu, u-boot

I am trying to run the u-boot on QEMU. But when start QEMU it gives nothing, so why this doesn't work and how to debug to find out the reason?

This is I tried:

1. Install `Ubuntu 18.04 WSL2` on Windows.
2. Compile u-boot for the Raspi2

   ```
   sudo apt install make gcc bison flex
   sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-none-eabi binutils-arm-none-eabi
   export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi-
   export ARCH=arm
   make rpi_2_defconfig all
   ```
3. Start QEMU

   `qemu-system-arm -M raspi2 -nographic -kernel ./u-boot/u-boot.bin`

   And also tried QEMU on the Windows side, and the result is the same.

   `PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> qemu-system-arm.exe  -M raspi2 --nographic -kernel E:\u-boot\u-boot.bin`

Then QEMU didn't give output, even I tried to `ctrl+c` cannot stop the process.
[image]

Comment: There are sime things that don't work when run in WSL2. Use a full Ubuntu VM using vagrant / virtualbox or similar

Comment: @Marged Hi, I also tried the QEMU on Windows, and the result is the same, so I think it due to WSL2.

Comment: It's always a good idea to check whether an issue is reproducible if you run QEMU on a Linux host -- very few of the upstream devs run Windows hosts, so Windows-only bugs get much less attention. However in this case I suspect the problem is that the -kernel argument is for running a Linux kernel, and QEMU does not provide the boot environment that u-boot expects (that is, it doesn't emulate the on-board firmware's boot code).

Comment: @PeterMaydell OK, I will try Linux VM.

Comment: Working fine with qem-arm/qemu-virt on Ubuntu 16.04 and qemu 4.1.1, but not with rpi_2/raspi2 ( I can display u-boot version in a telnet session in the case of the qemu-virt machine). I used the following commands: `make CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi- ARCH=arm mrproper qemu_arm_defconfig all` , `/opt/qemu-4.1.1/bin/qemu-system-arm -nographic -serial telnet::4444,server,nowait -machine virt -cpu cortex-a7 -bios u-boot-qemu-virt-arm.bin`, then built with `rpi_2_defconfig` and started qemu with ` -machine raspi2` and `u-boot-rpi_2.bin`

Comment: @PeterMaydell: is using nthe `-bios` with the u-boot binary image as a parameter correct in the case of the `raspi2` machine emulation ? thanks!

Comment: No, that won't work either: your u-boot binary probably doesn't expect to be run like that, and raspi2 doesn't support -bios anyway. https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-arm/2019-08/msg00681.html has a summary of how our raspi model can boot things, from the last time somebody asked this question. Neither of those are like the way that raspi2 hardware will boot the uboot binary blob, so I suspect you'll need to modify uboot.

Comment: @PeterMaydell: I see, thank you. I am perfectly happy with the qemu-virt machine.

Comment: Cool. I guess I'll summarise this conversation as an actual answer.

Comment: @PeterMaydell Actually I found what I want https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/boot_folder.md 
But also happy with a summary as the answer.

Comment: @Jiu: What would you think about accepting Peter Maydell's answer ? I find it very helpful and seeing it accepted  may help others to flag it for what is is, that is a  clear and valid one.

Comment: @Frant Because I need the device to be `raspberry pi` as mentioned in the question. The different machines will be meaningless to me. I am currently working on the raspberry pi device and trying to use QEMU instead of the real one.

Comment: @Jiu: I understand what your requirements are, but since your question was so `why this doesn't work and how to debug to find out the reason`, the provided answer does answer it IMHO: It does not work by design, and there is therefore no need to debug it in order to find why it is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this is an incompatibility between the way that u-boot expects to be started on the raspberry pi and the ways of starting binaries that QEMU supports for this board.

QEMU supports two ways of starting guest code on Arm in general:

1. Linux kernels; these boot with whatever the expected
   boot protocol for the kernel on this board is. For raspi
   that will be "start the primary CPU, but put the secondaries in
   the pen waiting on the mbox". Effectively, QEMU emulates a
   very minimal bit of the firmware, just enough to boot Linux.
2. Not Linux kernels; these are booted as if they were the
   first thing to execute on the raw hardware, which is to say
   that all CPUs start executing at once, and it is the job of
   the guest code to provide whatever penning of secondary CPUs
   it wants to do. That is, your guest code has to do the work
   of the firmware here, because it effectively is the firmware.

We assume that you're a Linux kernel if you're a raw image,
or a suitable uImage. If you're an ELF image we assume you're
not a Linux kernel. (This is not exactly ideal but we're to
some extent lumbered with it for backwards-compatibility reasons.)

On the raspberry pi boards, the way the u-boot binary expects to be started is likely to be "as if the firmware launched it", which is not exactly the same as either of the two options QEMU supports. This mismatch tends to result in u-boot crashing (usually because it is not expecting the "all CPUs run at once" behaviour).

A fix would require either changes to u-boot so it can handle being launched the way QEMU launches it, or changes to QEMU to support more emulation of the firmware of this board (which QEMU upstream would be reluctant to accept).

An alternative approach if it's not necessary to use the raspi board in particular would be to use some other board like the 'virt' board which u-boot does handle in a way that allows it to boot on QEMU. (The 'virt' board also has better device support; for instance it can do networking and USB devices, which 'raspi' and 'raspi2' cannot at the moment.)